# How to use the data from a structure in another C file?

Tags: c, ansi-c

I have defined a structure "data" in `Main.c`.

I want to use the values of this structure in a function of another file `app.c`.

Please suggest how to do this.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's C based on the question and title. I edited the tags to match that assumption...

Comment: Wait do you want to share a structure definition or the values of said structure?

Answer (score 4):

I assume you are asking about "c" and not "c#" since your question refers to ".c" files and not ".cs" files, etc:

Make a header file and put the struct there.

Include the header file in both Main.c and app.c

```
#include "yourFileNameHere.h"
```

Answer (score 2):

Usually you define a function prototype into a header file protected with include guards:

```
//module.h

#ifndef MODULE_H //include guard begin
#define MODULE_H

struct foobar{
   void *a_field;
};
void prototype(void);
#endif       //include guard end
```

Include guards prevent some including conflicts when different files need to include the same header. They guarantee it will be included only once.

Then you can include that header into a file with c extension that implement the defined prototypes:

```
//module.c

#include "module.h"

void prototype(void){
  //implement prototype function
  struct foobar f;

}
```

Usually every header file has a c file associated (that's not mandatory; it's a convention). If you need only to define structure you can even not need a C file associated with the header. If you have also some function prototypes to implement, that's a good way to organize your code.

Then include the header file in every other file that need the functions or structures defined inside it:

```
//otherfile.c

#include "module.h"
struct foobar f;
prototype(); //you can now call prototype function from this file
```

Now it's possible to compile and link together both files (prototype.c, otherfile.c)

Answer (score 0):

Since you say you want to reuse the values of the structure in a different source file I assume you defined a variable of your structure type in main.c like:

```
struct <mystruct> foobar;
```

If you want to use this same foobar in app.c, you have to declare that variable there as well, with the addition *extern*:

```
extern struct <mystruct> foobar;
```

Comment: i think the question is to reuse a structure 'definition' in a different C file, not a global variable of that struct type. i think we cant really extern a struct definition as such. externs are only for variables that occupy some tangible memory